# Unity build doesn't show colors right

Tags: unity-game-engine

When I wanted to build my game the colors were really wrong.
This is what the build should look like:

[image: click me]

This is how the build looks like:

[image: Click me]

I have tried everything from building the game again to changing the player settings. Does anyone know what can I do about this?

Comment: This looks like the common known "pink texture of death" :P ... it simply indicates that a Material/Shader is missing/broken .. how exactly do you setup your colors/Materials?

Comment: @derHugo the materials in the game are correct but the menu is wrong. I used textures for the menu. The buttons don't show up in other parts of the menu as well.

Comment: It would help if you included the build target and Unity version you are using. It looks like you got a shader error somewhere, so it could be your shader isn't compatible with the build target. Please also include the material you are using that isn't working.

Comment: My build target is windows and I am using the 2019.2.01f version (I am gonna update to 2020.01f soon). I have not added any shaders and only used the built in shaders. But for the menu I am using the UI shader. And the materials completly work(in my 3d scene). I am using colors for the main menu.

Comment: @IGamesI please rather upgrade to `2019.4 LTS` ;) You should stay with the LTS versions as long as possible except you really really need a new feature

Comment: @derHugo ok I will upgrade to 2019.4 LTS . plus my issue got fixed. the problem was that the always included shaders were section was corrupted so I added them back myself and the problem was fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the always included shaders part was corrupted(there was no shaders in them) so I added them myself and the issue got fixed.
[Click me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ClE3Q.png)